# Run nginx in dockerfile with backend and frontend parallel

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I run nginx in dockerfile with backend and frontend parallel?

This is for a new Linux server and I installed docker to run all service like nginx for backend and frontend.

Actually, I can run backend local with dockerfile but how to integrate with backend and frontend. Furthermore to run with server nginx ...

```
    version: "3"

networks:
  xukashopnet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.5.0/16
#       gateway: 10.0.5.1
services:
  xukashop-database:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: xukashop-db
    ports:
      - "8091:3306"
      - "33061:33060"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - .:/xukashop
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=xukashop
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456789
    networks:
      xukashopnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.5.2
  xukashop-api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - XUKA_SHOP_DATABASE_HOST=10.0.5.2
      - XUKA_SHOP_DATABASE_PORT=3306
      - XUKA_SHOP_DATABASE_NAME=xukashop
      - XUKA_SHOP_DATABASE_USERNAME=admin
      - XUKA_SHOP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=123456789
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - xukashop-database
    depends_on:
      - xukashop-database
    volumes:
      - .:/xukashop
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      xukashopnet:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.5.3
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample Dockerfile? I suspect the solution your looking for involves another tool like docker compose, swarm or kubernetes.

Comment: i use docker compose to run java spring-boot with mysql but i confused how to integrate with nginx to deploy ... can you give me some tutorial or example ? thanks

Comment: can you edit your question and copy-paste both your dockerfile and docker-compose file? I need more information to help

Comment: i recently updated my docker-compose for backend with mysql ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not running any frontend code with that docker compose file, only your api and db. Can you run through [this tutorial](https://dev.to/domysee/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-with-nginx-and-docker-compose-29jg) and let us know what the result is?

Comment: absolutely i don't run front-end at present but it will in the future ...

Comment: running the docker image for your frontend with docker compose should be fairly trivial. Adding nginx is more involved. Run through the tutorial I linked and let us know what happened.

Comment: updated: i really thanks for your help ... it makes me clearly mindset ...